# Render text on top of other text

Tags: html, css

I've got an element with some text in. Above that I have another element with exactly the same text in. I'd like for the text inside the top element to render over the top of the other text. However, when I run it, you can get noticeably different results whether the bottom element is shown or not.

https://jsfiddle.net/ag5nobc9/

This isn't too bad with black text, but starts to look bad if the top element's text is red or styled in some other way.

If you set opacity: 0, the problem disappears, but then the caret and text selection for the bottom element are no longer rendered by the browser, which hampers usability. I tried setting the font-weight on the bottom element but it doesn't seem to actually change the text in any way.

```css
.fixFontAttributes {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Monaco","Menlo","Ubuntu Mono","Droid Sans Mono","Consolas",monospace;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h3>With textarea</h3>
<div style="position:relative">
  <textarea class="fixFontAttributes" style="z-index:0;background-color:transparent;border:0px none;margin:0px;padding:0px">some text</textarea>
  <div class="fixFontAttributes" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:1;pointer-events:none;padding:0px;border:0px none;margin:0px">
    <pre class="fixFontAttributes" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;border:0px none;">some text</pre>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>Without textarea</h3>
<div style="position:relative">
  <div class="fixFontAttributes" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:1;pointer-events:none;padding:0px;border:0px none;margin:0px">
    <pre class="fixFontAttributes" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;border:0px none;">some text</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ideally I'd like a cross-browser solution to this or at least to understand what the problem is- Chrome produces the exact same problem as Firefox in this regard.

Just for complete clarity, what I'd like is for the text to appear normal - that is, as if the textarea didn't exist. It should be sharp and clear, not slightly blurry.

I've observed that if you simply render the div twice, the problem is lessened. It seems that the browser doesn't render the div's text with 100% opacity, even if you set `opacity: 1`, or it renders it with subpixel differences or something. It's still... thicker, somehow, but the colour is better.

[image]

Edit: It actually seems to occur regardless of which elements are being used, e.g. a pair of spans exhibits the exact same behaviour as a pre and a textarea.

Comment: What exactly is the *result* you're shooting for?

Comment: I want it to look the same regardless of the textarea's opacity - that is, for the textarea to have no apparent influence on text rendering.

Comment: While this is more a work-around than a solution: Why not replace the whole `<textarea>` text with the correct number of spaces? And whenever a user edits the `<textarea>` text, these user edits could then be applied to a string whose contents could be copied over to the `<pre>` whenever something was changed. Somewhat dirty though - I know. :S

Comment: That... might work. I already move the text over from the textarea to the pre. It would be a bit awkward to try to figure out what all of the events mean, but it might work. The only obvious downside is that when the user selects the text, they will be selecting just spaces, so drag and drop/copy and paste will not have the expected results.

Comment: Are you doing this because you want the text in the pre to be styled? not sure of the purpose.

Comment: Essentially, yes. I have everything that I want - I can style the text to my heart's content and I still have browser cursor, browser event handling, browser text selection, etc. The only problem is this text rendering problem.

Comment: But what exactly in those goals is not possible if you just use the textarea itself and style it?

Comment: But how would I style each individual character or span inside the textarea separately?

Comment: I'm really enormously confused. You want to magically add styling to the content that's being typed? That sounds like you're trying to create a code editor with syntax highlighting or something?

Comment: What's so difficult to understand? I want to style some text. It's not a complicated problem. My purpose behind styling the text is irrelevant.

Comment: The problem is not complicated on its own, it's just highly relevant for the solution. You would go about writing a JS code editor with syntax highlighting completely differently than a rich text editor. Neither of those includes a transparent `div` on top of a textarea though. Your question reeks of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/219504), in that you're intent on implementing a solution which most likely does not fit the actual problem at hand. People are trying to help you with that.

Comment: It fits the problem at hand just fine. I have everything I want. It's just this text rendering artifact which is problematic.

Comment: Perhaps there are limitations preventing you from using other approaches (which it'd be useful to describe here) but it would still be useful to explain your overall goal more clearly rather than focusing on the problems with your current method.

Comment: My overall goal is to present a textarea where I can style the text inside. That's my goal. Some of the JS code editors try to achieve similar outcomes, and I considered using one of them, but I observed some problems with e.g. text selection, and furthermore, their available input sources are quite limited, like ACE only seems to offer text styling if the text you want to style happens to match a regular expression, instead of arbitrary styling.

Comment: I have no idea why your most recent comment isn't right at the top of the question. It provides much-needed context.

Comment: Because my overall goal has already been fulfilled. The problem in the question is the only problem that needs consideration. I'll just suck up slightly inferior text rendering if I have to.

Answer (score -1):

This is a different approach, but have you considered using

```
contentEditable="true"
```

**Example:**

```html
<div contentEditable="true">
The text in this div can be edited.
</div>
```

Comment: Looks much more sensible to me, though I suspect there's a reason why this wasn't the approach in the first place. Hopefully the OP can clarify.

Comment: Yes, I have. I don't really want to use this approach because it allows the user to edit far too much - they can insert random HTML and mess with the styles and such. In my current implementation, they can only add/remove text, and the styles are entirely controlled by the code. The contenteditable div permits far more user freedom than I actually want to allow, especially since the contents of the box must be just text and nothing else. It would be very messy to get the correct input events and try to prevent bad input.

Comment: @Puppy that information looks like it belongs in the question.

Comment: Do you want to disallow any and all markup in the box? If so, you can simply use javascript to disable the input of angle-brackets. (If you're definitely sure you don't want to use `contentEditable="true"`, I'll not persist.)

Comment: People could still copy and paste, or drag and drop, or any number of other ways of putting non-text into the box.

Comment: Yes, but a `setInterval` function could fairly easily search and replace every few hundred miliseconds - so it wouldn't matter how they were trying to add the angle brackets to the `<div>`... the result is, those characters would never be there for longer than a fraction of a second.

Comment: Yes, but I actually need to permit those characters *as text*.

Comment: Yes, I understand that - I meant search and replace `<` as `&lt;` and `>` as `&gt;` - I'm sorry, I did say I wouldn't persist and here I am persisting. I'll drop it and go and do something else.